# Kotlin File(path).walkTopDown() does not find files

Tags: android, kotlin, file

I'm trying to read a given directory recursively and find all folders and files. The directory and subdirectory is found, but no files.

The storage structure on my virtual device:

[image: Local storage]

The code used to "walk through the given directory"

```
import android.util.Log
import java.io.File

// path = "/storage/1B10-1D17/ReadTest/"

class FileHelper {
    fun walkTest(path: String){
        File(path).walkTopDown().forEach {
//            println(it)
            Log.e("walkTest extension", it.extension)
            if(it.isDirectory){
                Log.e("walkTest", "Directory: ${it.name}")
            }else{
                Log.e("walkTest", "File: ${it.name}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will output the following:

```
E/walkTest extension: 
E/walkTest: Directory: ReadTest
E/walkTest extension: 
E/walkTest: Directory: SubFolder
```

In my android manifest file I have the following line and the permission is granted:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

What is the flaw in my code, how can I find the three pdf files stored in these directories?

**Update 1/2**
As can be seen in the screenshot below, the media access is granted:
[image]

If I run the following command (as suggested by dan1st), I get the following output, which shows that pdf file in place:

```
> adb shell ls /storage/1B10-1D17/ReadTest/
File_1.pdf
SubFolder
```

Comment: Did you [request the permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) and did the user grant the permission before?

Comment: @dan1st, I've granted the permission before, as you can see in the provided screenshot. I will do a double check on the link you've shared, maybe I've missed a step

Comment: What's the output of `adb shell ls /storage/1B10-1D17/ReadTest/`?

Comment: @dan1st, output: `
File_1.pdf
SubFolder`

Comment: What does `File(path).list()` and `File(path).listFiles()` yield in the app?

Comment: @dan1st: ```E/walkTest: File(path).list():
I/System.out: SubFolder
E/walkTest: File(path).listFiles():
I/System.out: /storage/1B10-1D17/ReadTest/SubFolder```

Comment: If you are using `ls -la` for the last command - what is the owner/group of those files/directories? Where they created by the root user?

Comment: @dan1st, thank you for your effort, I've finally found the fix. The permission requested was incorrect. Instead of `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, I needed to use `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` [as stated here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files). Since you provided the link that triggered me finding the answer, I'm more than willing to accept an answer if you write one where you state the mismatch (I'll provide my permission code checking in your answer than)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally have no access to arbitrary files on removable storage. This is not changed by `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Your proposed solution is to use `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Technically, this works, and it is a fine solution for personal-use apps. If your intention is to distribute this app, you will need to file paperwork with Google (and perhaps other app stores) justifying your use of this permission. Stores that disagree with your justification may elect to not distribute your app.

Alternatively, you can use the Storage Access Framework. Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree` and let the user decide where on the user's device (or in the user's cloud storage) the user wants your app to access the user's content. You can then use `DocumentFile` to walk the document tree to find sub-trees and documents.

Comment: The app is for personal-use, so for now I'm fine with using it. Nevertheless, this is a good answer since it will point future users to the proper way (if applicable) of doing things. Thank you for the elaboration